# Resetting table values through DateTime in Django

Tags: django, datetime, reset

I am attempting to create a voting database with an increasing number of names that are never deleted or reset. Votes are cast in the morning, and voting is closed around 10:00. I want to have a separate view that resets the votes back to zero for each instance in the afternoon, after the process is over. How might I accomplish this? Will I have to manually visit this view every day or can it be automated with a DateTime field as the parameter? I have a model to archive old results, but I want to re-use the voting models every day.

```
class restuarant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    percent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=23, decimal_places=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class totalVotes(models.Model):
    total = models.IntegerField()

class restuarantVote(models.Model):
    #voting model for statistic information
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    totalVotes = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

Answer (score 1):

as andrew suggested resetting data might not be the best approach.
Storing just the raw vote could provide a number of benefits:

1. you wouldn't have to worry about resetting the data each day. (which could require a cron job to update)
2. you could analize the data in any way you want.
3. it is more extendable.  You can build more flexible system, suppose you want to add user to the vote to track what a particular user likes?

That way you can see the vote for ANY day not just the current day.  You could change up your model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

throughout the day you could just add a vote when one is received

```
new_vote = Vote(choice=the_choice)
new_vote.save()
```

then to get the days vote:

```
todays_count = Vote.objects.filter(choice=the_choice, created=date_obj_here).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this kind of problem is almost always to eliminate the need for resets entirely.  If you can't figure out how to do this conceptually, consider posting more details on your model and application and what you mean by "resetting the votes".

If you absolutely need to run some kind of process daily to clean up your database, you can write a python script and import your application's settings and model file, and then run thej python script with cron on the server.  There are a few other too-clever solutions, but almost always you should reconsider your design first.

Edit: now that the code has been added to the question:  I recommend you make each restaurantVote represent a single vote cast by a unique individual, and remove the totalVotes IntegerField.  Create a new restaurantVote object for each vote cast.  You can add a datetime or date field to restaurantVote to mark when it was cast.  When you want to total votes, do a query to total up the number of votes for each choice between the beginning and the end of a given day, or just for the given day if you are using a date field instead of a datetime field.

If you don't want to do that, you can keep the IntegerField on there but just add the date field.  Every time someone votes, look to see if there is a restaurantVote for that choice and the current day already; if not, then create it (you may be able to use get_or_create() for this).

By the way, if restaurantVote is supposed to be a vote cast for an individual restaurant, then you can use a foreignkey relationship instead of a CharField for choice.